# Where to insert parameters in Postman

Tags: syntax, get, postman

I'm new to Postman Client and have created a GET Request where URL is as following:

```
  https://www.foo.bar/api/script.php/1/1
```

The PHP File identifies the two parameters and the response is okay. As you can see, there are two parameters for identifier "1" and type "1" that I set manually above.

Now I wanted to "automatize" it. In Postman Client, there is a button to the right of the URL: "Params". I suppose, that here, I have to insert the two parameter values, but I don't the syntax how to do this for "key", "value".

Is there a guideline or step-by-step documentation how to use Parameters?

Comment: In a GET request, you pass parameters as part of the query string. You might want to have a look at https://www.getpostman.com/docs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either you use that button to create two parameters with their value (let's say param1 and param2) and your url will update as follows:
https://www.foo.bar/api/script.php/get?param1=1&param2=1

or create global variables (click on the eye at the top right corner) and use them in your url as follows:
https://www.foo.bar/api/script.php/{{param1}}/{{param2}}

one of those should work ...